# How to fetch users from OU @activedirectory

Tags: node.js, express, active-directory

I'm using with npm activedirectory to fetch users from AD.
I need help to get object users. I'm using with find(baseDN) but my OU result is wrong

Thanks for help.

var baseDN = { baseDn: 'OU=Users, OU=Users1, DC=domain, DC=com' };

```
ad.find(baseDN, function(err, users) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }

  if (! users) console.log('User: ' + baseDN + ' not found.');
  res.status(200).json( users );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out instead:

```
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
ad.find("OU=akshay,OU=testContainer,dc=domain,dc=com", function(err, users) {
  if (err) {
console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
  return;
  }
  if (! users) console.log('User: ' + baseDN + ' not found.');
else {
console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
  }
});
```